# Ionic 3 And Open Layer 4 not display when open new page

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, openlayers

I try to build a simple app using openlayer.I use Ionic 3 and Open layer version in my `package.json`: `"openlayers": "^4.6.5",`

My page.ts:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, Renderer, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
    import { IonicPage,Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

    import OlMap from 'ol/map';
    import OlXYZ from 'ol/source/xyz';
    import OlTileLayer from 'ol/layer/tile';
    import OlView from 'ol/view';
    import OlProj from 'ol/proj';

    @IonicPage()
    @Component({
      selector: 'page-open-map',
      templateUrl: 'open-map.html'
    })

    export class OpenMapPage {

      map: OlMap;
      source: OlXYZ;
      layer: OlTileLayer;
      view: OlView;

      constructor(platform: Platform, public renderer: Renderer) {
        platform.ready().then(() => {
          console.log("Platform is ready");
          this.loadMap();
        })
      }

      loadMap() {
        this.source = new OlXYZ({
          // Tiles from Mapbox (Light)
          url: 'https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.light/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw'
        });

        this.layer = new OlTileLayer({
          source: this.source
        });

        this.view = new OlView({
          center: OlProj.fromLonLat([6.661594, 50.433237]),
          zoom: 3,
        });

        this.map = new OlMap({
          target: 'map',
          layers: [this.layer],
          view: this.view
        });

      }

    }
```

My html file:

```
 <ion-header>

      <ion-navbar>
        <ion-title>OpenMap</ion-title>
      </ion-navbar>

    </ion-header>

    <ion-content padding class="about">
      This is my super awesome about page.
     <div id="map" #map class="map" ></div>
    </ion-content>
```

When I build this app the home page is ok, but when I open a new page, my page doesn't show the map. Is there something wrong in my code?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

In your html, try to put div outside ion-content

Answer (score 0):

This is no need to use the `platform.ready()`, your app should be ready when you try to "open a new page".

Can you try this?

```
    constructor(public renderer: Renderer) {}

    ngAfterViewInit() { 
      this.loadMap()
    }
```

I would also never instantiate nothing in the constructor, but would try to move it into the `ngAfterViewInit()` [Lifecycle hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks), because, when instantiating it into the constructor, your `target: 'map'` or better say the `<div id="map" #map class="map" ></div>` may not exists yet.

`ngAfterViewInit` is triggered once the DOM is fully loaded

So doing so may fix your problem